# UITableView Scrolls to Top on Cell Refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITableView with a cell that is dynamically sized to fit a UITextView inside it. Whenever a key is typed, the cell checks to see if the calculated height has increased, as with a newline, so it can tell the table the the cell's height needs to be recalculated. I do that with this code.

```
- (void) createNoteCellViewDidUpdate: (CreateNoteCell*) cell {

    CGFloat newHeight = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:CreateNoteCellIndexPath];
    if (newHeight != CGRectGetHeight(cell.contentView.frame)) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates]; // <- HERE IS WHERE THE CONTENT OFFSET CHANGES
    }
}
```

The resize and table bounds are as expected. But instead of just animating the change in height, it also scrolls to the top. This can be seen here, when pressing the return key.

[image: table scrolling on cell resize]

By Key Value Observing, I've found out that the scroll view contentOffset is being set when the scroll view's contentSize changes. And that the contentSize changes many times when the endUpdates method is called. When it changes it goes from a normal height, to a rather large height, then back to a normal height. I wonder if it's going to top because of that. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Question - why are you trying to resize your tableview instead of just resizing the cell?  Normally the frame of a tableview stays constant and it's content changes.

Comment: No, I'm not touching the Table View frame or bounds. I'm resizing the cell by telling the table view to recalculate all the heights of the cells.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wow, Josh Gafni's answer helped a lot; he deserves an upvote. My solution is based off his. This still feels like a hack, so if anyone still has a better way to do this, I'm still very interested to hear it.

First I save the content offset, then I start the update.

```
CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This animates the cell's height change and adjusts all the frames to suit the constraints.

Next I remove all animations from the tableView's layer, so the animation to the top stops. Then I reset the contentOffst to what it was before.

```
[self.tableView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
```

Finally, I let the tableView handle the animated scroll down so the bottom of the cell is right above the keyboard.

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:CreateNoteCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

And voila, it works pretty well.

[image: fixed cell resize]

Comment: I've been having almost the exact same issue, but have so far had no luck getting this solution to work.  I was wondering, are you doing anything to ensure that your UITextView cell appears above the keyboard (e.g. updating the contentInset)?  Also, have you found any refinements to this solution?  Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU, just what I needed.

Comment: If I could Tinder superlike this post, I would.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my UITableView extension that works perfectly. In Swift 2.1. Based on the accepted answer.

```
extension UITableView
{
    func reloadDataAnimatedKeepingOffset()
    {
        let offset = contentOffset
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        beginUpdates()
        endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        layoutIfNeeded()
        contentOffset = offset
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for 'UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(...)'

Answer (score 8):

Just a guess...

Save the `contentOffset` of the uitableview before any changes.  Then set it again after.

```
CGFloat contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
```

and then after the changes

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
```

Comment: Yes, but this has the problem where the contentOffset is set by the ScrollView, then set by me. So the animation starts to bring it to the top, then I come in mid-animation and bring it back. So it animates up, then down, which gets very annoying after the height takes up the whole screen.

Comment: One thought (a bit of a hack) could be to subclass tableView and overwrite `setContentOffset`.  the `contentOffset` must be set to 0 at some point for the jump to occur.  Add a bool property to the tableview called `isUpdatingCellHeight` and only when this variable is `NO` does is actually update `_contentOffset`.  So before updating the table set it to `YES` and after set it to `NO` and then set the `contentOffset` as I mention above.

Comment: Your first way with some animation-canceling trickery made it work. I think it's a little more elegant than subclassing. I don't want to limit it from it's normal cell-height adjusting operations, just in this one case it needed to be reversed.

Answer (score 4):

More simplified solution (add Notification observer when textView is changed), Swift-version. Main trick is using `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled`.

```
func textViewDidChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that method existed. Thanks!

Comment: @Jadar, thank you, if that method is working and simplier that original solution please mark it as answer. If it was helpful you can at least vote for it, so other users can easily find it.

Comment: I don't currently have a means of testing it as I'm not using this bit of UI anymore. I'd be more inclined to do so if you had more comments explaining like the currently accepted answer.